# Azure Data Factory ADF Schema validation for JSON

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I am implementing a feature which is validating a dataset schema.
I know that in ADF there is a checkbox in the Mapping Dataflow section which does it automatically if columns or type of the column does not match against the reference.
For CSV it works fine for me, but in case of JSON I noticed two thing:
1, when I created a Dataset for the JSON its schema is different what I see in the Mapping Dataflow although I use the same dataset. I tried every option at both (Dataset & Data Flow) places import from sample file, import projection etc.. w/o success

[image: sameDataSetDifferentSchema.png]

At the end in the Dataset I changed it manually in the code part by editing the JSON's JSON :)

[image: changeSchemaOfDataset.png]

2, lastly it does not solved the problem after having the same Schema it is still failing during schema validation.

[image: ErrorMsg.png]

However in the error msg itself it dispalys the same type if you see the screenshot:

Found: `ArrayType(StructType(StructField(**Description1**,StringType,true),...etc`
Required: `ArrayType(StructType(StructField(**Description1**,StringType,true),...etc`

Answer (score 0):

Instead of changing the data type in the dataset JSON, just override it in the data flow.

In the Projection tab of the Source transform, click "Import Projection" to override the dataset schema.

If you're not getting the schema that you want, then modify it using a Derived Column with toInteger() for the string you wish to convert.

Comment: after I clicked in the Data flow/ Source / Projection / Import Projection I assume the data is analyzed and ADF repopulated the types, which is not the same what I see in the Dataset I tried to validate with and without modifying the dataset json's json but have not got it validated. Derived column would not be ok since I would like to validate the schema in the first node before doing any transformation (derived column for ex.) . But is not that a bug since even the error msg is contradictive for me since the 'Source' and 'Required' pairs are reflecting the same types.

Comment: Dataset validation won't work in this scenario since your projection is different from your dataset schema.

Comment: JSON validation is not possible in general (if yes how)? I made something wrong (if so what) ? Is it a bug ? The projection and dataset after I modified the JSON's JSON in data set manually showed the same as it can be seen in the first comment print screens.

Comment: Are you looking to validate data type? If so, you'll need to compare data types in a Derived Column pattern match using typeMatch() https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/data-flow-expression-functions#typematch